# Own cite command

Tags: citing

I want to create a certain cite command that is pretty similar to the original one:

```
\newcommand{\mycite}[2][]{\hspace{30pt}\cite{#2}{#1}}
```

The problem is that when I only write `\mycite{test}`. Then there will be

> [Test, ]

but it should be

> [Test]

because I omitted the optional argument.
I tried it with the package `xparse`. But there I got the same result with the following code

```
\NewDocumentCommand\mycite{O{}m}{%
  \cite[#1]{#2}%
}
```

What do I do wrong? Could you help me?

Comment: Please be aware that some of the `\cite` - related packages do redefine `\cite` to provide more optional arguments already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no check if the optional argument of `\mycite` is present or not. So `\mycite{#2}` will still call `\cite[]{#2}` with an empty optional argument for `\cite`, meaning to typeset `,` in the list.

I added the 'traditional' way to check for the optional argument and the `xparse` method (much easier!)

**Note**: Bibliography related packages might change the `\cite` command already. This is not covered here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\@myotherciteopt}[2][]{%
  \hspace{30pt}%
  \ifblank{#1}{%
    \cite{#2}%
  }{%
    \cite[#1]{#2}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\@myothercitenoopt}[1]{%
  \@myotherciteopt[]{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\myothercite}{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@myotherciteopt}{\@myothercitenoopt}%
}

\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand\mycite{om}{%
  \hspace{30pt}%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \cite[#1]{#2}%
  }{%
    \cite{#2}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\mycite{Lam94}

\myothercite{Lam94}

Now with options:

\mycite[Ms. Ann Elk]{Lam94}

\myothercite[Ms. Ann Elk]{Lam94}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

[image]